# Create a "score" based on the characters contained in a specific cell in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

We use an in-house scoring system for gauging the quality of our wares by creating a code based on the characteristics of the individual ware, and adding/subtracting points based on the characters contained in the code. For example, in the code `Fw-BPs`, we say

```
F = +1
w = -1
- = -1
B = +1
P = +1
s = +1
```

so `Fw-BPs` would receive a score of `2`, because `0 + 1 - 1 - 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 2`.

If `A1` contains the code `Fw-BPs`, what formula could I use in `B1` to create the score?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a lookup table of characters like my screenshot. They you may try-

```
=SUM(INDEX(XLOOKUP(INDEX(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)),D1:D6,E1:E6,0)))
```

You can also define character values inside `XLOOKUP()` as array like-

```
=SUM(INDEX(XLOOKUP(INDEX(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)),{"F","w","-","B","P","s"},{1,-1,-1,1,1,1},0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Can it differentiate between capitalized and uncapitalized? I want w to be -1 but W to be +1. thanks

Comment: @hermancain Then we have to go with different approach.

Comment: anything that works. Appreciate your help

Comment: Which one your are following. Lookup or insdie formula declare values?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Find instead of Xlookup if you needed it to be case-sensitive:

```
=SUM(INDEX({1,-1,-1,1,1,1},FIND(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),"Fw-BPW")))
```

[image]

This wouldn't work in Google Sheets but you could try:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(xlookup(FIND(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),"Fw-BPW"),{1,2,3,4,5,6},{1,-1,-1,1,1,1})))
```

[image]